Getting an error while enabling migration into my Visual Studio project
I am trying to enable migrations into my project but I am getting this error
PM> enable-migrations


System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'PPWorkplace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

I have tried adding this to my web.config also  but still  there is no change, also I don't see any unblock button  when I navigate to the properties of the project...
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>


You need to either adding loadFromRemoteSources switch in exe.config or unblock the dll file in your project.here's the ps command:
Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse | Unblock-File
